# Best way to generate random number between two sets of values

Tags: javascript, random

I need to generate a random number that's between -40 and -10 and 10 and 40. So the results could be 25, but never -5 or 5.

I've looked online, but the solutions seem overly complex. Is there any way to do it in just one or two lines?

Comment: What solutions are overly complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a number between 10 and 40 and then generate a 1 or 0, if 0 convert it to negative 1 and multiply by either result
`Math.random() * 30 + (Math.random() < 0.5 ? -40 : 10);`

Comment: What's the most elegant way to write this?

Comment: var result = Math.random() * 30 + (Math.Random() < 0.5 ? -40 : 10);

Comment: @MattHouser, nice simplification

Comment: That'll work too, but requires calling random() twice, which will be twice as slow as necessary. Also, he seems to want integer values.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, 2 calls to random is not a huge speed hit this obviously isn't a performance critical application and my solution is more elegant and readable than yours not to mention more extendable to other cases

Comment: Also the solution is not hard to adapt to integer values but he didn't actually specify and javascript has no ints so I assumed this would be fine

Comment: True, your solution is more readable and that's good. But performance always counts. I work for a casino. I write simulations that run *billions* of hands of blackjack or poker. If I doubled the number of calls to my generator, I would essentially double the running time of the whole simulation. Of course, I also wouldn't be caught dead using Javascript, but that's another discussion...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, fair enough i ran both urs is about 25% faster

Answer (score 3):

Math.random() will return a random number between 0 and 1.

Create your own function to create a random number between your min and max numbers.  Scale a random number between your min and max, then offset by you min value.

```
function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: It doesn't, but I came here from a Google search looking for this exact piece of code though. I can now continue writing code, instead of Googling :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's 62 distinct values, 31 in each subrange, so:

```
r = Math.floor(Math.random()*62);
if (r < 31) { r -= 40; } else { r -= 21; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = Math.random()*62;
return n - (n < 31 ? 40 : 21);
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar. Change those constants to 62, 31, 40, and 21. OP specified inclusive ranges.

Comment: Thought I might have been susceptible to an off by 1 error. I really shouldn't attempt writing code this late.

Comment: That's better. OP seems to imply integers, though. Not sure if that's really what he wants or not.

Comment: Right..well we can floor that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=15;i<=46;i++)
{
    double random=Math.rand()*5+i; 
    int rand=(int)random;
    System.out.println(rand);

}
```

The above code generates the random number between 15-50

```
Math.random()*5=i
```

This gives the lower value i.e 15 here in this case

Note: you need to subtract 4 from the upper bond of the value i.e here if u use i<=50 this will be printing no up to 54  ,  similarly if you want to generate no. b/w 50-80 use (int i=50;i<=76;i++)

hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
It could be tricky but definitely the best way is to write your own function.

```
var random = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2;

if (random >= 0){
    random = lerp(10, 40, random);
} else {
    random = lerp(-40, -10, Math.abs(random));
}

function lerp (min, max, value){
    return (1 - value) * min + value * max;
}
```

**Explanation:**

There are **(3) three steps** you need to follow in order to achieve what you need.

1. A random number **(between -1 and 1)**.

   ```
   let random = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2
   ```
2. An **if condition** to know if the value is negative or positive.

   ```
   if (random >= 0){ /* Is Positive */ }
   else { /* Is Negative */ }
   ```
3. Lerp between the values you need (**-40 to-10** if negative or **10 to 40** if positive).

   ```
   // This function interpolates between two numbers based on a normalized value (between 0 and 1)
   function lerp (min, max, value){
      return (1 - value) * min + value * max;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm is (rand*(max-min))+min

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+10
```

and

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*-30)-10
```

Comment: He wants to generate a single number given the conditions.